# subquery - return data from unrelated table?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Just wondering if you can get data from a subquery, even if the main query doesn't return any hits?

```
$query = "SELECT `affiliateID`, `password`, `companyName`, `contactName`,
(SELECT loginAttempts FROM lockoutRecord WHERE attemptedUsername = '$user' AND accountType = 'Affiliate' ) as attemptCount,
(SELECT lastAttemptTime FROM lockoutRecord WHERE attemptedUsername = '$user' AND     accountType = 'Affiliate' ) as lastAttemptTime
FROM `affiliates` WHERE `email` = '$user' LIMIT 1";
```

In the above example, the user's login attempt doesn't find a hit for that user in the affiliate table, but I'd still like it to return loginAttempts from lockoutRecord to see how many times attempts have been made on that user name

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: To get data to where? If your main query did not returns rows, that is an issue of a whole query, you can not separate subqueries from it. If you need to do so, simply make a separate query as you are doing it in your subquery

Comment: loginAttempts and lastAttemptTime can be stored through SESSION and handled directly by PHP (thus no additional db communication required). Would it not be more easier ?

Comment: Cheers guys. I've had people get past session lockout pretty easy, and wanted something database driven so they can't delete the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution

```
SELECT affiliateID, password, companyName, contactName, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime
FROM
(
    SELECT '$user' user 
) u LEFT JOIN affiliates a 
    ON u.user = a.email LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT attemptedUsername, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime
      FROM lockoutRecord 
     WHERE accountType = 'Affiliate' 
) l ON u.user = l.attemptedUsername
```

Sample output:

```
| AFFILIATEID | PASSWORD | COMPANYNAME | CONTACTNAME | LOGINATTEMPTS |     LASTATTEMPTTIME |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      (null) |   (null) |      (null) |      (null) |             2 | 2013-08-09 13:00:00 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/310a5/2)** demo

Comment: Wow - slotted it in and it worked perfectly Peter. I've not used SQLFiddle beofre - does the donation go to you? Thank you btw.

Comment: @Shaun You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help :) SQLFiddle is made by Jake Feasel (a lot of thanks to him) and if you feel like you can and want to donate please do it by all means to support this awesome resource. I'm just a fan and regular user of this resource.